# Install 32-bit ubuntu on new 64-bit machine

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit

I have a new hp 2020 laptop, which is obviously a 64-bit machine. I need to develop some projects on the DSP board, and required SDK can only be installed on a 32-bit machine (I have a binary installation file, which I cannot shared due to a license issue). I did the installation of 32-bit Ubuntu (16.04 Xenial) on the virtual machine without problems. So then, I've created a bootable USB with iso image, which however wouldn't boot from bios (nor from ubuntu itself). I've read online that this problem comes from the fact that 32-bit Ubuntu doesn't have UEFI boot. Please give me suggestions, how can I install 32-bit ubuntu on a new 64-bit machine in a dual boot mode or at least create a USB which could be launched from BIOS.

I want to assure you that I've spent a few hours googling for similar questions but couldn't find an answer. I had no problem creating bootable USBs and CDs for 64-bit OS, however, has this unfortunate problem with 32-bit.

Thanks everyone for help!

Comment: Indeed application can be installed, however only in terminal mode (in 32bit OS the GUI version starts). But after that, application simply doesn’t start. Oh, and application I’m talking about is xtensa Xplorer 6.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

> required SDK can only be installed on a 32-bit machine (I have a binary installation file, which I cannot shared due to a license issue)

Linux multilib is 100% compatible with 32bit software. There's no need to install a 32bit OS directly, just install the missing required 32bit libraries and you're good to go.

Ubuntu 18.04 would be a better fit because from what I've heard for newer releases the number of available 32bit packages has been reduced significantly.

Answer (score 0):

I've always just used balena etcher for ISO booting, but you can also just mount the iso as a disc and copy the contents of it onto the usb. If that boots fine, you should have no problem getting it installed while you're on the live usb